# Como traer registros que estén en una tabla pero que no existan en otra?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola un saludos para todos.

Como puedo hacer para que mi consulta solo traiga los registros que se encuentran en una tabla pero que no existan en otra?

Las tablas son las siguiente:

seguridad_raci : esa es la tabla principal que almacena el registro
seguridad_planraci : esta es la tabla secundaria que almacena otros datos del registro y se relaciona con el id_ra de la tabla seguridad_raci.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
$sqlfor = ("SELECT * FROM seguridad_raci,seguridad_planraci WHERE seguridad_raci.id_ra!=seguridad_planraci.refepltr GROUP BY seguridad_raci.id_ra");
$mostarfor = mysqli_query($cn, $sqlfor);
```

El gran problema es que me trae todos los registros y solo debería traerme uno solo el cual no tiene datos registrados en la tabla seguridad_planraci.

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A ver, creo que esta es una tarea para JOIN, la unión LEFT JOIN te va a listar todos los registros de la tabla izquierda (la primera, en este caso seguridad_raci) y mostrará los regitros de la segunda (seguirdad_planraci) cuyo refepltr coincida con el id_ra de la primera (supongo que estos campos son los que ligan ambas tablas). Si en la primera tabla hay registros que no están en la segunda, se mostrará un NULL
Algo lioso ¿no? Otra forma de decirlo es que forma una tabla con todos los registros de la primera y junto a cada uno pone el correspondiente de la segunda, pero si este no existe pues pone un NULL.
Si filtramos los registros que muestran null en la segunda tabla tienes lo que buscas.

```
SELECT *, sp.refepltr as sp FROM seguridad_raci AS sr
LEFT JOIN seguridad_planraci AS sp ON sr.id_ra = sp.refepltr 
WHERE isnull(sp.refepltr )
```

Pongo sinónimos (sr y sp) para escribir menos, no por vago :) sino para que el código quede más limpio y claro.
He añadido en el select sp.refepltr por si quieres probar con y sin WHERE.
Probablemente el select tengas que detallarlo con los campos de ambas tablas que quieras mostrar (sp.* y sr.*)
Espero que te sirva.